# Why aren't multiple transactions recommended in pg_query?

Tags: php, postgresql, transactions

The PHP postgresql documentation says:

> The SQL statement or statements to be executed. When multiple
>   statements are passed to the function, they are automatically executed
>   as one transaction, unless there are explicit BEGIN/COMMIT commands
>   included in the query string. However, using multiple transactions in
>   one function call is not recommended.

But why does it say that multiple transactions are not reccommended? Also, if they are not recommended how would you do something fancy like an upsert?

Also, I wanted to use pg_query_params because it auto-escapes parameters, but it doesn't allow multiple transactions at all. Is there a safe and effective way to do multiple transactions?

Comment: There is a diffrence between a transaction and statement. Upsert should be done in a single transaction (and can in fact be done with a single statement).

Comment: Why would you *want* to do multiple transactions in a single query? That makes no sense. It's also a terrible idea because it gives you very little useful information when errors occur. Did the first transaction fail then the second fail? etc.